# Issue Creating MongoDB Collection with Next.js and Mongoose

Tags: reactjs, mongodb, mongoose, next.js, postman

**Issue Description:**

I'm working on a 3D printing website and facing difficulties with my MongoDB database. I have two collections, `Printer` and `Filament`, with their respective schemas as shown below:

Printer Schema:

```json
{
    "price": Number,
    "name": String,
    "image": String,
    "bg": String,
    "availability": String,
    "speed": Number // (mm of filament)/s
}
```

Filament Schema:

```json
{
    "price": Number,
    "name": String,
    "image": String,
    "bg": String,
    "length": Number
}
```

I'm currently working on a POST method to create a new `Filament` object in the database.

**Folder Structure:**

[folder structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8SVjy.png)

**MongoDB Atlas Configuration:**

[Mongodb Atlas](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6zGCi.png)

**Postman Request:**

[PostMan](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0eMJD.png)

**Code:**

**route.js:**

```js
import Filement from "@/models/filement";
import { NextResponse } from "next/server";
import { connectMongoDB } from "@/libs/mongodb";

export async function POST(req) {
    const {price, name, image, bg, length} = await req.json();

    await connectMongoDB();
    await Filement.create({price, name, image, bg, length});

    return NextResponse.json({ message: "Filament created successfully" }, { status: 201 });
}
```

**mongodb.js:**

```js
import mongoose from "mongoose";

const connectMongoDB = async () => {
    try {
        await mongoose.connect(process.env.MONGODB_URI);
        console.log("Connection to Database: OK");
    } catch (error) {
        console.log("Connection to Database: FAILED");
        console.log(error);
    }
};

export default connectMongoDB;
```

**filement.js:**

```js
import mongoose, { Schema } from "mongoose";

const filementSchema = new Schema({
    price: Number,
    name: String,
    image: String,
    bg: String,
    length: Number
});

const Filement = mongoose.model.Filement || mongoose.model("Filement", filementSchema);

export default Filement;
```

**Issue Details:**

I've tried to change the `MONGODB_URI` variable multiple times, and I'm certain it's correct. I've also reset the server and confirmed the URL. Dependencies are installed, but a new collection is not being created in MongoDB Atlas as expected.

I appreciate any insights or solutions to this issue.

[Here are the errors I encoutred myself with](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5h0mM.png)

[for anyone that wants to see the full repository](https://github.com/AU0758/3d-printing)